# What encoding setting do I need in MySql to support mathematical symbols?

Tags: mysqli

I need to support the following symbols:  π, ∑, ≥, ≠, ≤, ∞, α, Ω, ←, ◊ in a C# application with a mysql back end.

I have tried setting charset = utf8 (in both the database and connection string), collation = utf8_unicode_cl

and I get "Incorrect string value" errors trying to save.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### UPDATE:

I've just installed **MySQL Server** and **HeidiSQL** client to my PC, selecting UTF-8 as default server charset.
Also I created a test database and a table as follows:

**The database:**

```sql
CREATE DATABASE `test` /*!40100 CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci */
```

**The table:**

```sql
CREATE TABLE `math` (
    `id` INT(10) NOT NULL,
    `symbol` CHAR(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
ROW_FORMAT=DEFAULT
```

Then I inserted one by one some symbols, copying and pasting them from your post, and from this [other page](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?103,383708,383708). This is the table after the inserts:
[image: math table after inserts]

The following is my server configuration:
[image: server settings]

I hope this information will be actually useful for you

---

Also, check these links:

- [Unicode](http://docs.moodle.org/en/Unicode):

  > Free On-line Unicode Character Map
  >   gives you the possibility to see the
  >   different characters that are
  >   supported (or NOT!) in your browser
  >   and see which code is used if you need
  >   that. A nice feature with the
  >   characters is that you can easily
  >   enlarge the text in your browser to
  >   see them better. ([Ctrl]+[+] in
  >   Mozilla) If you are interested in Math
  >   symbols check list "22 Mathematical
  >   Operators". For Chemists looking for
  >   arrows, list "21" might be
  >   interesting.
- [Mathematical UTF-8 Special Characters](http://www.wizcity.com/Computers/Characters/MathematicalUTF8.php)
- [Unicode 6.0 Character Code Charts](http://www.unicode.org/charts/)
- [Mathematical Symbols in Unicode](http://tlt.its.psu.edu/suggestions/international/bylanguage/math.html)
- [Collation chart for utf8_general_ci, European alphabets (MySQL 6.0.4)](http://www.collation-charts.org/mysql60/mysql604.utf8_general_ci.european.html): Blocks: Basic Latin, Latin1 Supplement, Latin Extended-A, Latin Extended-B, Latin Extended Additional, Latin ligatures, Greek, Greek Extended, Cyrillic, Cyrillic Supplement, Armenian, Georgian
- [Other MySQL collation charts](http://www.collation-charts.org/mysql60/)

Comment: Those are helpful links, albeit many that I'd already been looking at, but don't ultimately answer the question.  After review, it looks to me like the answer is that it's not possible w/MySql.  I'll mark this as the answer, but if anyone actually has the answer, please opine.  Thanks.